# React Native: Animated components only run once

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation

I am creating a circular carousel in React Native
The design is there are some items on the circle, and when the user clicks up button or down button, it will move the items to up or down.

here's [image]

Now, I can able to make the items move only one times using the React Native Animated
but I don't know why it only move one time? If I click one more time on the go up button, it's not moving anymore

Here's the code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Animated, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

function degToRad(deg) {
  return (deg * Math.PI) / 180;
}

export default class Circle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //usersList: ['A'],
      usersList: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    };
    this.animations = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.usersList.length; i++) {
      this.animations.push(new Animated.ValueXY(this.returnXY(i)));
    }
  }

  returnXY = index => {
    let degree = (index * 360) / this.state.usersList.length;
    const { size, symbolSize } = this.props;
    const angleRad = degToRad(degree); //45
    const radius = size / 2;
    const center = radius;
    let x = radius * Math.cos(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;
    let y = radius * Math.sin(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;
    return { x, y };
  };

  constructoCircleElements = () => {
    let object = [];
    const { symbolSize } = this.props;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.usersList.length; i++) {
      let animation = this.animations[i].getLayout();
      object.push(
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.symbol,
            {
              width: symbolSize * 2,
              height: symbolSize,
              borderRadius: symbolSize / 2,
            },
            animation,
          ]}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{this.state.usersList[i]}</Text>
        </Animated.View>
      );
    }
    return object;
  };

  goUp = () => {
    console.log('GO UP');
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.usersList.length; i++) {
      let { x, y } = this.returnXY(i + 1);
      Animated.spring(this.animations[i], {
        toValue: { x, y },
      }).start();
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { size } = this.props;
    let displayList = this.constructoCircleElements();

    return (
      <View>
        <View
          style={[
            styles.circle,
            {
              width: size,
              height: size,
              borderRadius: size / 2,
            },
          ]}>
          <Text style={styles.circleCaption}>A</Text>
          {displayList}
        </View>
        <Button title={'UP'} color="black" onPress={this.goUp} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  circle: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderRadius: 500,
    borderStyle: 'dotted',
    borderColor: '#fff',
  },
  circleCaption: {
    fontSize: 70,
  },
  symbol: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    position: 'absolute',
  },
});
```

https://snack.expo.io/@rex_rau/sponaneous-yogurt
Inside the Circle.js

I assume that because I didn't update the item x and y to the newest state?
but I am not sure what to do?

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving the current indexes of your circle items. I have modified your code a little bit:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //usersList: ['A'],
      usersList: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    };
    this.animations = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.usersList.length; i++) {
      //Here I added index 
      this.animations.push({
        value: new Animated.ValueXY(this.returnXY(i)),
        index: i,
      });
    }
  }

  returnXY = index => {
    let degree = (index * 360) / this.state.usersList.length;
    const { size, symbolSize } = this.props;
    const angleRad = degToRad(degree); //45
    const radius = size / 2;
    const center = radius;
    let x = radius * Math.cos(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;
    let y = radius * Math.sin(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;
    return { x, y };
  };

  constructoCircleElements = () => {
    let object = [];
    const { symbolSize } = this.props;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.usersList.length; i++) {
      let animation = this.animations[i].value.getLayout();
      object.push(
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.symbol,
            {
              width: symbolSize * 2,
              height: symbolSize,
              borderRadius: symbolSize / 2,
            },
            animation,
          ]}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{this.state.usersList[i]}</Text>
        </Animated.View>
      );
    }
    return object;
  };

  goUp = () => {
    let temp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.usersList.length; i++) {
      //Here I increment the count
      let { x, y } = this.returnXY(++this.animations[i].index);
      let animation = Animated.spring(this.animations[i].value, {
        toValue: { x, y },
      });
      temp.push(animation);
    }
    Animated.parallel(temp).start();
  };

  render() {
    const { size } = this.props;
    let displayList = this.constructoCircleElements();

    return (
      <View>
        <View
          style={[
            styles.circle,
            {
              width: size,
              height: size,
              borderRadius: size / 2,
            },
          ]}>
          <Text style={styles.circleCaption}>A</Text>
          {displayList}
        </View>
        <Button title={'UP'} color="white" onPress={this.goUp} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/@bungler/sponaneous-yogurt) is snack for testing!

Comment: May I ask a question, why adding the temp inside Parallel will make it work? I thought the parallel only for two different animations?

Comment: It will work without `Parallel` as well. I added it for code quality!